# Installing Ubuntu-22.04.1 on HP Envy Laptop Not Working

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, hp

I have an HP Envy Laptop that previously had Windows 11 on it. However, I just got a new desktop and decided to switch my laptop OS entirely to Ubuntu for work related activities.
I was able to convert a USB I had into a live disk using Rufus and tried to run a fresh install.

I was able to get to the GRUB GNU menu and selected the "Try or Install Ubuntu" option, but selecting that option ended up stuck at the manufacturer's logo with Ubuntu logo at the bottom and the loading circle continuously spinning.
Pressing ESC, it seems to be continuously cycling through three different lines:

- (1 of 3) A start job is running for Network Name Resolution
- (2 of 3) A start job is running for Network Time Synchronization
- (3 of 3) A start job is running for Userspace Out-Of-Memory (OOM) Killer

[Before saying that they failed to start and continuing the cycle all over again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPbw1.jpg)

Seeing that this isn't the first time this question has been posted to the board, I tried the solutions to others who have asked this previously but to no avail, including:

- Force shutting down the laptop and turning it back on again
- Wiping the drive using the terminal on a Windows 10 USB
- Adding `nomodeset` and `nouveau.modeset=0` after `/casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu. seed maybe-ubiquity quiet splash` in GNU GRUB
- Trying the "Ubuntu (safe graphics)" option
- *Edit*: Disabling Secure Boot in the UEFI settings

If someone could point out where I went wrong, please! I really need to get this machine working!

Comment: Because your goal is to have Ubuntu only you can and should disable Secure Boot in UEFI. But before that update UEFI itself. Keeping Windows until you do is probably the best course of action. HP tends to release its BIOS/UEFI updates in Windows executable files only.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Windows OS has already been completely wiped from the laptop since it was one of the solutions I tried previously. Would it work if I installed Windows 10 again and removed Secure Boot afterwards? Also may I ask what you mean by updating UEFI itself?

Comment: UEFI ("BIOS") is the firmware and yes, there are often updates and should be applied in this situation. Secure Boot is a UEFI feature, it has nothing to do with Windows or any other OS.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I turned Secure Boot off but it still gets stuck at those 3 steps as stated previously

Comment: You of course verified the ISO you downloaded before making the boot USB? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: @David Yes I did

Answer (score 0):

I had the same behavior wile booting with a Ubuntu 22.04 boot stick. Bevor that I made a distupgrade from 21.10 to 22.04 on the same notebook and was not able to boot the standart Kernel. I think it was 5.15.25. Selecting the previous 5.13.x Kernel it started up.
With the boot option ACPI=off the live stick started. So I believe it's related to a ACPI related bios/UEFI bug.
BUT: trying the new Ubuntu 22.10 USB Stick, it started up. So the problem might be solved. I still need to do a fresh install to verify that for the actual installation.

Comment: it appears this is fixed with 22.10.  Was running into this issue on an HP ENVY 15z and was able to boot using a bootable 22.10 usb.